# Push or Local notifications alerting user to change between saved and remote data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

in my football club's betting app I'm thinking of implementing some sort of `notification` for the user. 
Currently, the app will check the server and compare the bets of the two people betting and then tell the user if his opponent has raised the bet. 
By the way this is all fake money, who ever accumulates the most money at the end of the season will win a small prize, I don't want to get done by the gambling authorities! Anyway, I was hoping that when the bet has been reached the user will be notified even if they're out of the app. What sort of `notification` would I need to use to do this?

The bet saved by the user is saved in Core Data and it's opposing bet will be on the server.

It would be cool if the app could just run for a bit in the `background` and do all the `calculations` that it already does, then post a `notification`.

That would be easy! But sadly, from what I've read it's far more complex than that. However, I'm not sure which type of notification I'd use.

I hope I don't have to do it via push because that seems like pretty tough stuff. If you could make a recommendation and a brief outline of the steps I'd be really grateful.

Regards,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood your problem, there's no other solution than using Push Notifications since you need be notified when the app is in background.

- You could simply pull the new bets from your server and fire a [local
  notification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW13), but the app needs to be foreground (there's a [solution](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW28) to download data while background but it's far from being perfect).
- The correct way: Take a look at [Apple's Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html) and build a notification system in your server to push notifications to your apps. I know it seems hard at the beginning, it is way easier than it seems, I strongly recommend you to take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12) by [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/).

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks ender. I actually read that tutorial earlier and it kind of put me off somewhat as I'm not sure I could code the server side stuff. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Would just like to reply to something you said: "it is way easier than it seems" - I'm struggling lots!

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not the answer you're looking for, but this is precisely what push notification was designed for. See the [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1).

While it would seem appealing to have you app check for updates periodically in the background, but background operation is restricted to a [very few types of apps](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24), something for which your app would not appear to qualify.

Comment: Thank you very much I appreciate the reply. I guess I'll have to do Push Notifications.