# Buying servers for Push Notifications

Tags: iphone, ios

Because of the outcome of another question I asked: [Push or Local notifications alerting user to change between saved and remote data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683219/push-or-local-notifications-alerting-user-to-change-between-saved-and-remote-dat)
I have decided to tackle Push Notifications head on. I don't, however, really know where to begin when buying a server. Once I start following tutorials and the like, I should be good to follow along relatively unchallenged, but I'd hate to buy a server not capable of running background processes, installing SSL certificates, and making outgoing TLS connections on certain ports (Those were the requirements on one tutorial). Could anyone recommend a company that offers servers at relatively cheap prices since I don't want to spend huge amounts on it, and have the correct specifications for push notifications. I live in the UK, but since I'm localising the app a couple of countries, would it be worth having the server in another country?

Anyway, any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Regards,
Mike

Comment: this question is likely to be closed.  But there are tons of other services, like Parse.com & Urban Airship that do this.  If your going for the server, just google, then send them an email.  Burst.net is works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would consider using a service like Urban Airship to start. https://go.urbanairship.com/accounts/register/

It'll be free until you are doing more than 1 million pushes a month and will save you the hassle of setting up a server.

Comment: Absolutely perfect answer. Thanks for this. Don't really know why topic has been closed but glad you posted the answer before it was.

Comment: No problem. I would also say that you could use this service to start and eventually transfer off of it in the future but the convenience is worth the cost IMO.

Comment: Well I have been looking around and setting everything up. The problem is, there doesn't seem to be any way to run my own PHP scripts and MySQL databases to set up the calculations for the push notification.

Comment: Oh I gotcha. Urban Airship will only solve half of your problem. I would suggest just setting up a cheap shared server to start or a free amazon ec2 instance to get going. That's a much bigger process than can be described in an answer like this. If all you need to do is broadcast pushes then urban airship would work great by itself.

Comment: Right thanks rooster. I guess it's a pretty big job, and I think I may hire in people to do it for me. Hopefully some web developers who work nearby can help.